# Getting distinct result with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data structure

```
ID  | REFID | NAME
1   | 100   | A
2   | 101   | B
3   | 101   | C
```

With

```
SELECT DISTINCT REFID, ID, NAME
FROM my_table
ORDER BY ID
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
1   | 100   | A
2   | 101   | B
```

Colum NAME and ID should contain the MIN or FIRST value.

But actually I get stuck at using MIN/FIRST here.

I welcome every tipps :-)

Comment: Look into `ROW_NUMBER`, it will do what you need.

Comment: And what should `id` have?  Do you want the `min(id)` too?  The `id` from the row with the `min(name)`?  Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select id,
       refid,
       name
  from (select id, 
               refid,
               name,
               row_number() over(partition by refid order by name) as rn
          from my_table)
 where rn = 1
 order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to do this.

```
WITH Q AS 
( SELECT MIN(NAME) AS NAME, REFID FROM T GROUP BY REFID )
SELECT T.ID, T.REFID, T.NAME
FROM T
JOIN Q 
  ON (T.NAME = Q.NAME)
```

Also, note that SQL tables have no order. So there's no "First" value.